# Hard to pin non-regular language with pumping lemma

Tags: theory, regular-language, finite-automata, state-machine, pumping-lemma

I'm having trouble proving a particular language is non-regular. The language is defined as

> L<sub>a</sub> = { *wz*:  w,z ∈ {0,1}* and |w| > |z|}

I don't know how to approach this one. No matter what string I choose, I always run into the issue where w and z are moving targets for me; I haven't been able to create a string which couldn't be pumped or otherwise contradicted. Any thoughts on the right direction for this one?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was part of a homework set, and apparently this question wasn't worded properly and is in fact regular.